# Get 'Allow all the time' location React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, permissions, location, expo

I'm building an app that requires full access to the location in the background. The app is working well in the old android version but not on android 10 and next. Tt's not working because the prompt about getting always access to the location is not showing up.

I'm working with React Native and Expo 38

Comment: Try to follow the react native documentation of PermissionAndroid

Comment: hi did you fine any answers on how to allow location all the time ???